# Parsing a Javascript object from online resource

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm attempting to parse a Javscript object online using nodejs.

This file for example: http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Leluc8SAAAAAElzN1CrcweqVxkUfmGa7QC40pUU

This is not JSON, and is regular JavaScript. I have managed to parse out the JavaScript object using:

```
/* Data is the JS file above */
var j = data.substring(data.indexOf('{'), data.indexOf('}') + 1);
```

But, how do I parse that so I can read it as an object? `JSON.parse` doesn't work because its not JSON formatted.

***Edit***

As the `challenge` key is what I require, I ended up solving it with `substring` and `indexOf`:

```
var start = data.indexOf('\'');
var end = data.substring(start + 1).indexOf('\'');
var challenge = data.substring(start, (start + end) + 1);
```

But I'd still like to know a solution to the origional problem. And yes, I could use `"'"` but in this project we stuck to using single quotes and I'm a stickler for making sure everything is in line with the style guide. Silly I know, just a habbit.

Comment: there's always `eval`, if you trust that server to not spit out `nuke_my_system()`-type malicious code...

Comment: I can't imagine Google doing that, but I also don't trust `eval` just incase. I'm the super paranoid type.

Answer (score 0):

#### In the browser

This should work on client-side JavaScript :

```
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.src = "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Leluc8SAAAAAElzN1CrcweqVxkUfmGa7QC40pUU";

document.body.appendChild(js);
```

It adds the external file to your HTML. The JavaScript inside is run once it's been loaded.

---

#### Node.js

In node, I'd take this road :

1. Do an HTTP request to get the code
2. Save that code as a text file
3. `require` the file you just saved

If you take that road, your code should look something like this :

```
require("request")("http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Leluc8SAAAAAElzN1CrcweqVxkUfmGa7QC40pUU", function(error, response, body) {
    require('fs').writeFile('./stuff.js', body, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        var stuffIJustLoaded = require('./stuff.js');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was using node. I best add that to the description.

Comment: I understand it's as bad as eval, but the source of the data is Google, and the application runs in a VM on my machine whos sole purpose is pulling captchas for analysis. In this instance I can make an exception.

Comment: @BugHunterUK : I think saving the code and then requiring it is still a cleaner option than `eval`, although it does indeed remain quite "hacky". I may be wrong, but I don't think there's any less hacky option you have, though.

Comment: @BugHunterUK : Anyway, do let me know if the approach I suggested in my updated answer works out for you. I honestly haven't tried it myself yet, but it's what I would do in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

well the simplest way is the following for this particular issue.

```
var x = JSON.stringify({
    challenge : '03AHJ_VuuiaIB_izO6VJ6PifXI8A8i1yBeG6biCjadtaZHk5pbxfbW5JPpEXBEay-LPdCzSOI1bQgdnjq1tQVSqzQ63hMQB1Sjlho4LdzfZKLXuK3TKZD1YPr5bIjM-dYqHIkcYpaanchXOXLkHNoj0B6_ZrUk4rZg-o790H1LMNzoPGy3qkk6suYWs1CERFjkTO_mw9puMnYQNITPzBnRS-QMilbch2d_PeM2aDGToLSQiLn8mgHwP7fUHvCcE9VGzNZNXkDC8wF-YvUCxU354VqeSa8U7KKycg',
    timeout : 1800,
    lang : 'en',
    server : 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/',
    site : '6Leluc8SAAAAAElzN1CrcweqVxkUfmGa7QC40pUU',
    error_message : '',
    programming_error : '',
    is_incorrect : false,
    rtl : false,
    t1 : 'Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9qcy90aC9PejNvSUJCSlYxanlWSi13QTFqRndDd3dhbk5QVTh2TGd6SWVaNGc2TkxnLmpz',
    t2 : '',
    t3 : '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'
});
console.log(JSON.parse(x).challenge);
//03AHJ_VuuiaIB_izO6VJ6PifXI8A8i1yBeG6biCjadtaZHk5pbxfbW5JPpEXBEay-LPdCzSOI1bQgdnjq1tQVSqzQ63hMQB1Sjlho4LdzfZKLXuK3TKZD1YPr5bIjM-dYqHIkcYpaanchXOXLkHNoj0B6_ZrUk4rZg-o790H1LMNzoPGy3qkk6suYWs1CERFjkTO_mw9puMnYQNITPzBnRS-QMilbch2d_PeM2aDGToLSQiLn8mgHwP7fUHvCcE9VGzNZNXkDC8wF-YvUCxU354VqeSa8U7KKycg
```

Comment: I get an error: `undefined:2
    challenge : '03AHJ_VutWM1RaNjTPTM-7m_IzY-AB6hYgINnJrbxLMhnj0RvXGnnbANB6ixsRFyjzoj6DgqFDM5Vi0KVD0lOK1EIsQCacBZUowsNe0cLifIJP85pWWqpfzcLcUNHNfKvdWU7oVKIGZIS3I3HNv67YPdGp-xz57DLHO8utBpHGKaa-4GXePxDVxUsjvFDiah0F2bz7rNCsTye_pYkoybIM0WhzV6fLr5iOjA',`

Comment: i just tried it on my node....
u need to do JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(....)).challenge

Comment: I had a blonde moment, I did it the other way around. Works fine, thank you.

Comment: Just to update, this fails when loading the data from the source. The challenge is undefined.

Comment: when u load it from source u just save it in a local variable.... if you show me the source code maybe I can see the problem